# Limit stdout from a continuously running process

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, output

I haven't had much luck finding an answer to my problem, but maybe I'm not asking for it correctly.

I have a process I startup like the following:

`nohup ping 127.0.0.1 > log.txt >2>&1 &`

Pretty simple command, send all the stdout to log.txt.  Only problem is that the command I'm running sends data every nth second to log.txt.  I'd like to output just one line to my log.txt file instead of appending it and running the risk of filling my drive up.

Is there a way to just output one line to log.txt that continuously gets overwritten?

Comment: This would require a `seek(0)` before every write, or closing and reopening the file for each write.

Comment: Why have a file in the first place if you are just going to continuously overwrite it?  Just run it in a `screen` or `tmux` session.  The other approach if you really want a file, is to pipe the output to a simple script that does the overwriting for you (read n lines, overwrite file, ad infinitum).

Comment: Writing to a file is not mandatory, I just need to pickup the latest output from the command in a webpage (some shell_exec call in php).  Is it possible to just redirect the output to something that I can call and see what it's doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty solution to only keep the last line of output in the log file:

```
ping localhost | 
  while IFS= read -r line; do 
    printf '%s\n' "$line" > log.txt; 
  done
```

Beware that you now probably have all kinds of race conditions when trying to access the file for reading. "Locking" the file from mutual access might help. For more information about locking this question on stackoverflow might be a good start: [How do I synchronize (lock/unlock) access to a file in bash from multiple scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319091/how-do-i-synchronize-lock-unlock-access-to-a-file-in-bash-from-multiple-script)

Answer (score 0):

Try this script, it works for me:

```
% nohup ping 127.0.0.1 > log.txt >&1&
```

Check if the process is running by typing:

```
% ps ax | grep ping
```

If the process is running:

```
% tail -f log.txt
```

If it continues pinging, your script is working properly.